# How to encrypt a column using nifi

Tags: python, encryption, apache-nifi

For security reasons I need to encrypt a column before putting the data in the repository.
How can I do this using python or some processor.
I tried to use the cryptography library but without success.
If you can guide me which is the best way I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [ScriptedTransformRecord](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-scripting-nar/1.15.3/org.apache.nifi.processors.script.ScriptedTransformRecord/index.html), it should allow you to do arbitrary operations on whichever field/columns you like. If you're using a Python library, remember that the script engine is Jython and cannot import modules that aren't pure Python (CPython modules for example). Java has crypto libraries so you could achieve this with Groovy instead.

There is a [Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-2961) to cover an EncryptAttributes processor, but perhaps there should be one for Expression Language and/or RecordPath functions as well.